# Sorting a list vs sorting two sublists

Tags: sorting

I'm finding the unambiguously least element in a list. To do this, I've sorted the list and then just picked the first if it's less than the second.

Now I have two sublists instead of one big list. If I perform the same process on the two sublists, and then merge the results (just sort them as a two-element list, effectively), is that guaranteed to produce the same outcome as if they were sorted in one big list?

Currently, for a one-element list, there is no second element for it to be not less than, so I treat it as the single unique minimum element.

Comment: Why not just go through the elements one by one, keeping a running minimum and a flag for whether you've seen the minimum twice?

Comment: Well, it's not that simple when you don't know if you've seen the minimum yet, since the minimum could be later. It's much easier to just sort, the log(N) factor is irrelevant to me.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the running minimum is the real minimum. If the next item is less than the running minimum, make it the running minimum and clear the flag. If it's equal, raise the flag. If it's greater, do nothing. At the end, you know the minimum, and you know whether it's unique.

Comment: This is still totally not worth it compared to my current approach, implemented with a comparator and two statements, instead of a comparator and an algorithm.

Comment: But you care about a possible constant-factor improvement in the two-list case? I mean, if you want to write less code, you could just take the min of the list and then count how many times it occurs. Anyway, the answer to the question you asked is no, unless you do some case work. I'm writing up a longer answer currently.

Comment: Please define "sorted the list" with respect to "merge", in context, as you *appear* to be saying that your merge does a sort. Can you show some code?

Comment: @user: I don't care about that. I only care about making sure the answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Let's analyze algorithm. There are three cases:

#### 1. One list has unique minimum element, but other not, for example:

a) `[2, 3, 3]` - unique minimum element: `2`

b) `[1, 1, 2]` - no such element

Merged results: `[2]` - unique minimum element: `2`

Big list: `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]` - no such element

So in this case outcome **not the same** - **FAIL**.

#### 2. Both lists do not have a unique minimum elements:

It is obvious in this case outcome the same (no such element) - **OK**

#### 3. Both lists has unique minimum elements:

a) `[a1, a2, ...]` - there a1 < a2 and `a1` - unique minimum element

b) `[b1, b2, ...]` - there b1 < b2 and `b1` - unique minimum element

If a1 = b1 then:

Merged results: `[a1, b1]` - don't have unique minimum

Big list: `[a1, b1, ...]` - don't have unique minimum

If a1 < b1 (the same logic for a1 > b1) then:

Merged results: `[a1, b1]` - unique minimum element: `a1`

Big list can be `[a1, b1, ...]` or `[a1, a2, ..., b1, ...]` - unique minimum element: `a1` because a1 < b1 and a1 < a2

So in this case outcome the same - **OK**

### Conclusion and proposal

The algorithm will fail only in first case, so can be easily improved.

*My suggestion to improve:*

When one list has unique minimum element and other not then as results merge three elements: unique minimum element (`a1`) from one list and two minimal elements from other (`b1` = `b2`).

*Analysis of improvement:*

If a1 = b1 then outcome the same in merged results and in big list (no unique minimum).

If a1 < b1 then:

Merged results: `[a1, b1, b2]` - unique minimum element: `a1`

Big list can be `[a1, b1, b2, ...]` or `[a1, a2, ..., b1, b2, ...]` - unique minimum element: `a1` because a1 < b1 and a1 < a2

If a1 > b1 then:

Merged results: `[b1, b2, a1]` - don't have unique minimum because b1 = b2

Big list: `[b1, b2, ..., a1, ...]` - don't have unique minimum because b1 = b2

Outcome the same - **OK**

**Modified algorithm will work in all three cases!**

Comment: I thought about it some more, and I actually *want* that failure behaviour in case 1, so I'll stick with my existing solution. Thanks for your work-through, it really helped me think through what the scenarios were and what the behaviour was.

Answer (score 0):

No, or at least not simply. If your code currently returns either the minimum or a "minimum not unique" indicator, then it doesn't give enough information. If the following lists are input:

```
list1 = [1, 1]
list2 = [0]
```

then running your procedure on list1 will just tell you the minimum isn't unique, and you won't be able to tell that the two lists together have a unique minimum of 0.

If your code returns the minimum together with an indicator of whether it's unique, you can do it with some casework:

```
min1, min1unique = uniquemin(list1)
min2, min2unique = uniquemin(list2)

if min1 == min2:
    return min1, False
elif min1 < min2:
    return min1, min1unique
else:
    return min2, min2unique
```

I would recommend combining the lists into one list first. Also, I would recommend avoiding the sort:

```
minimum = min(l)
minimum_is_unique = l.count(minimum) == 1
```